# Problemas com o Left Join com EclipseLink - Java

Tags: java, jpa, vraptor

Estou com um problema com a seguinte query:

```
SELECT * FROM tipo_calibracao t LEFT OUTER JOIN fator_medio f ON (t.id = f.tipo_calibracao AND f.lote = 42) ORDER BY t.id ASC;
```

Java:

```
 public List<TipoCalibracao> searchTypes(Long batchId) {
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM tipo_calibracao t " +
            "LEFT JOIN fator_medio f ON (t.id = f.tipo_calibracao AND f.lote = #batchId) ORDER BY t.id ASC", TipoCalibracao.class);
    query.setParameter("batchId", batchId);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Executando ela no mysql ela retorna o que eu espero:

```
'1', 'MO', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
'2', 'P', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
```

que seria a tabela tipo_calibracao normal e a tabela fator_medio nulla, porém rodando a mesma query no Java ela retorna um resultado antigo para a tabela fator_medio, mesmo realizando o check pelo lote, o qual seria o mais atual.

Estou usando o EclipseLink.

Comment: "*porém rodando a mesma query no Java ela retorna um resultado antigo para a tabela fator_medio, mesmo realizando o check pelo lote, o qual seria o mais atual.*" - Ou seja, isso dá a entender que é algum problema de cache ou de isolamento de transações. Como você não colocou nenhum código em Java, fica difícil te dizer o que tem de errado nele.

Comment: Acabei de colocar o codigo Java. Então eu imaginei que poderia ser problema de cache, porém mesmo restartando o servidor ele continuar retornando um valor antigo.

Comment: De onde e como você pega esse `EntityManager`?

Comment: Eu tenho um arquivo BaseDAO, ai eu herdo ele dessa classe.

Comment: Acredito que o seu `EntityManager` não esteja sendo gerenciado corretamente. Como é que esse `BaseDAO` o gerencia?